# How can i check apple default app in apple watch simulator?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, extension-methods, watchkit

Just started apple watch programming.

I want to know that is there any way to check all the installed apps on the apple watch simulator as in the iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is a bit different from iPhone apps. When you install iOS 8.2+, Apple Watch app is automatically installed. If you open this app, you can check what apps are installed with WatchKit extension and also, you can use it to lock notifications.

[image: AppleWatch app simulator screenshoot]

[image]